# how to configure cloudfront to retrive static images from the s3 bucket?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-cloudfront, kubernetes-ingress

i am doing a task related to CDN. my Question is i need to configure application load balancer for the cloudfront . i need static images from the s3 bucket and all other content from the kubernetes pods. suggest me some good methods to do it. the simple thing is if a client hits the url of my website the static images need to came from cloudfront not from the server.

expecting some good methods

Comment: any update on this ? if any of your below answers your question please do update the status of question by accepting answer or you can write your custom solution too. You can also upvote if found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use Two Domain

- cdn.domain.com
- main.domin.com (ingress setup)

Whenever you are building your Artifacts on **CI/CD** you can push **static** **files** to those **S3** **CDN** buckets.

The user will call the `main.domain.com` which will load the initial file to the browser and your **CDN** objects will be called & served by nearby **cache** server.

If you want to handle it in single **Ingress** or **Service mesh** by **Path based routing** can also do that using **External** **service** which will point to your **CloudFront** or **LoadBalancer** **IP** backed by S3.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use 2 behaviours and route based on a URL prefix.

Say you have a DNS entry mydomain.com.
Redirect this DNS entry to your CloudFront distribution.

Create

- a behaviour associated with /static and using your S3 bucket as origin.
- a second behaviour associated with /api and using your K8S ingress URL as origin.